# Neural net performance using rmse

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, r, forecasting

I am trying to build a NN which can predict exchange values. I am quite new to R and NN and I don't quite understand how I could improve the performance metrics of the neural network. I have tried adjusting the threshold and learning rate as much as I could before it stopped improving the result. Can I improve the result further and at what point do you stop and accept the result?

I have added a link to the datafile because some code works on the smaller snippets of the dataset but sometimes don't work in the full dataset

Dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17exy1968lsidsc/ExchangeUSDcsv.csv?dl=0

Code:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(grid)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)
library(neuralnet)
library(zoo)

normalize <- function(x){
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min (x)))
}

exchangeData <- read.csv("ExchangeUSDcsv.csv")
data <- exchangeData$USD.EUR
data <-as.data.frame(data[!is.na(data)])

#delay the data
currencyDelay <- embed(data[[1]], 4)[, 4:1]

#delay and normalize 
currencyNorm <- embed(normalize(data[[1]]), 4)[, 4:1]

currencyNorm <- as.data.frame(currencyDelay)

training <- currencyNorm[1:400,]
testing <- currencyNorm[401:497,]

set.seed(1234)

currency_model <- neuralnet(V4 ~ ., hidden = c(5), data = training, act.fct = "logistic")

#Get the model to predict
model_results <- compute(currency_model, testing)
#Store models predictions
predicted_result <- model_results$net.result

#Get original train and test data
currencyDelay_train <- currencyDelay[1:400,]
currencyDelay_test <- currencyDelay[401:497,]

#Find min and from the data
cur_min <- min(currencyDelay_train[,4])
cur_max <- max(currencyDelay_train[,4])

#reversed normalization
unnormalize <- function(x, min, max){
  return ((max-min)*x + min)
}

#Un-normalize the predictions
models_predictions_unnorm <- unnormalize(predicted_result, cur_min, cur_max)

#Stat Indicies
rmse(currencyDelay_train[4], models_predictions_unnorm)
mae(currencyDelay_train[4], models_predictions_unnorm)
mape(currencyDelay_train[4], models_predictions_unnorm)

#Compare Actual results with NN prediction
final_result <- cbind(currencyDelay_train[4], models_predictions_unnorm)
head(final_result)
```

Current outputs:

```
RMSE:
0.04519089
MAE:
0.04519089
MAPE:
0.03294277
```

Comment: Could you say, what is a value before unnormalization?

Comment: I mean, it seems you normalized with parameters with whole dataset and unnormalize with data for train only. The normalized/unnormalized coeffs should be the same.